# ManyToMany relation table's field name for an existing schema

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

I'm using Symfony 4.4 where I have to *get data from a legacy database by entityManager*.

There are 2 tables `artist`, `fun_fact` and a relation table `artist_fun_fact`.

**Artist.php**

```
  /**
   * @var FunFact[]|null
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Legacy\FunFact", inversedBy="artists")
   * @ORM\JoinTable(name="artist_fun_fact", schema="legacy")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="artist_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  private $funfacts;
```

**FunFact.php**

```
  /**
   * @var Artist[]|null
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Legacy\Artist", mappedBy="funfacts")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fun_fact_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  private $artists;
```

and the relation table has the following fields (**which I unable to modify because Database and Entities are read only**):

- artist_id
- fun_fact_id

When I run the code, i got the:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'legacy.artist_fun_fact.**funfact_id**' in 'on clause'

message. It's clear that my `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="fun_fact_id", referencedColumnName="id")` directive is uneffective but I have no idea how else could I tell to the ORM that the field is she looking for is `fun_fact_id` instead of `funfact_id`

thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: What if you change it in `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="fun_fact_id", referencedColumnName="fun_fact_id")` ?

Comment: @Agnohendrix thank you for your suggestion but that's an error, because referenced column should point to the referenced entity's unique id.